# Convergence in a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, compactness

My professor asked me to prove or disprove the following claim:

Let $C \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a compact set. Let $x_n\in C$, be a sequence such that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} |x_{n+1} - x_n| = 0. \quad (1)$$

Then $x_n \to x$ for some $x \in C$.

My analysis:

The existence of a limit point is assured by the property of compactness (every sequence has a limit point). We worked on disproving the claim. To do this, we assumed that the sequence had 2 limit points and there were 2 subsequences that were converging to those points. However we had difficulty disproving $(1)$.

On the other hand, while trying to prove it, assume a subsequence $x_{n_k} \to x$. Then
$$|x_n - x| \leq |x_n - x_{n_k}| + |x_{n_k} - x|$$
The second term goes to $0$ as $k$ becomes large. For now assume $k$ large enough so that second term is $< \varepsilon/2$. Let $n>n_k$. But handling the first term is quite hard. Triangle inequality yields
$$|x_n - x_{n_k}| \leq \sum_{l=n_k}^{n-1}|x_{l+1}-x_l|\leq (n-n_k)\varepsilon$$

However it seems pointless to take $n$ or $k$ large at this step.

We tried several counterexample attempts but none successful. Could someone kindly offer a hint as to proceed? We would appreciate it.

Update:
Thanks to von Eitzen.
By mean value theorem,
$$|\sin(\sqrt{n+1}) - \sin(\sqrt{n})|= \frac{|\cos(\sqrt{\theta})|}{2\sqrt{\theta}}\leq\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$$
where $n\leq \theta \leq n+1$. So the sequence $\sin (\sqrt{n})$ is valid but it does not converge. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $C=[-1,1]$ and $x_n=\sin\sqrt n$.

Comment: Thanks. I just updated my answer with the analysis.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{+\infty}|x_{n+1}-x_n|=0$ doesn't mean $(x_n) $ is Cauchy.

it will be true if

$$|x_{n+1}-x_n|\le K|x_n-x_{n-1}|$$ with $K\in (0,1) $.

Comment: We are aware of that. But because this sequence was in a compact set, we had our doubts.